# How can I set a session for multiple links that I want to disable?

Tags: php, session, get, voting

piece of file1.php:

```
<a href="file2.php?addid=1">Add this to DB</a>
```

This takes the user to a page where the data gets inserted into the database.

file2.php :

```
 $clicked = $_GET['addid'];
 $_SESSION['clicked'] = $clicked;
 // data gets inserted
 header("Location: file1.php?id=$clicked");
```

But I have got multiple pages (like: file1.php?id=1 | file1.php?id=2 | file1.php?id=3 etc.).
Can the session variable handle multiple numbers? Is there any way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

(P.S.: Currently I am using the GET method to disable the links, but I think SESSION is more reliable.)
(P.P.S.: I need this for a voting script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hold more data in one session variable, you need to create a multi-dimensional array which will hold multiple against `$_SESSION['checked']`. You can do this like:

```
$clicked = (int)$_GET['addid'];
$_SESSION['clicked'][$clicked] = true;
// data gets inserted
header("Location: file1.php?id=$clicked");
```

(also, you should be sanitizing `$_GET['addid']`.

Then to check if it is set, you can use `array_key_exists`:

```
if(array_key_exists($clicked,$_SESSION['clicked'])){
  echo "this button should be disabled!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood right your question, but if it is how to send an array of data with the same id via an http request you can use this syntax for the url

```
file.php?arr[]=val1&arr[]=val2&arr[]=val3
```

from your php code you would access the values as a regular array

> Can the session variable handle multiple numbers? Is there any way to do this?

The session variable can store an array

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION['clicked'] this session variable can store one value at a time.
  If you want use 2 dimension array to handle multiple values.

$clicked = $_GET['addid'];

Ex: $_SESSION['clicked'][$clicked];

Answer (score 1):

firstly concatinate all the ids with comma in a string as $var = 1,2,3,4 and then pass it using GET.

Then there on that page you can explode it from comma and can store it in array and then foreach loop for the array will do it for you. Hope it works.